Short story about girl back from a Narnia-like portal trip
A few years back, I found a short story that I'd like to find again. The basic premise was that the main character was a woman who as a girl had stepped into a portal into a fantasy world—much like Narnia—and had grown up there and saved the world and all that, but was now back on Earth. And on Earth, she was ultra-paranoid and now carried lots of survival gear with her just in case she was going to go back through the portal—and she kept trying to go back. I seem to recall that in the ending she finally admitted to herself and her brother(?) that she wasn't ever going to go back.
I seem to recall also that she had a bunch of things hanging from her belt, like a flashlight, knife, and for some reason I want to say a CD containing the Encyclopedia Brittanica, but I might be misremembering that detail. There was a lot of emphasis on how the first time she went to the fantasy land she wasn't prepared, but this time she would be, and had all the things she needed that first time.
I think I encountered it online in Uncanny Magazine or Strange Horizons in the 2022–2023 year range, but my memory may not be very good on that at this point, and it may have been from earlier than that. I've tried going through the old issues to no avail so far.
I would love to find the story again, though. Anyone know what it might be called?

It feels like it might be story set in Seanan McGuire's Wayward Children universe. Does the description I've linked ring any bells?

@JohnRennie Hm, in the story I remember, the girl was the only one who went to the fantasy land, and when she came back part of the deal was that no one believed her, and thought her sudden interest in survivalist things to be crazy. I also am pretty sure it was a standalone, and not part of a continuing series.

The Lost Legend of Finn had that as a quirk too, but I think it was her brother who was always carrying gear (him having been the one who took more to the adventure).

I sent a twit to Seanan McGuire to see if she might recognize it as her work. :) She's usually fairly happy to answer questions.

Ah, and confirmed it's not one of hers. https://x.com/seananmcguire/status/1832435617466347812

Haven't found anything, but obligatory XKCD comic at https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/693:_Children%27s_Fantasy
